# ASP.NET identity password policy not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity

I recently started learning backend and I was working on my auth controller when I encountered this issue with the password policy

I have ASP.NET identity configured like this:

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectManagementDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
    options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
    options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;

    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
});
```

but I tried to register multiple times and it didn't work so I added this exception to see exactly what's going on:

```
public async Task<ApplicationUser> CreateUser(ApplicationUser user, string password)
{
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, password);

    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        return user;
    }

    var errorMessage = string.Join(", ", result.Errors.Select(error => error.Description));

    throw new ApplicationException($"Failed to create user. Errors: {errorMessage}");
}
```

This is what I got:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgBud.png)

Comment: Ziad, the supposed image with errors that you must have posted is not visible. So it's not clear what is the problem exactly.

Comment: Idk what am i doing wrong but anyways here's the link to the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgBud.png

Answer (score 0):

Try register password option in this way

```
PasswordOptions passwordOption = new PasswordOptions()
        {
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequiredLength = 8,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequireUppercase = true,
            RequireNonAlphanumeric = false,
            RequiredUniqueChars = 0
        };
```

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser,IdentityRole>(option =>
            {
                option.Password = passwordOption;
            })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ProjectManagementDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```